# For $a\in R$ . calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$( $( a+\frac{1}{n})^2 + (a +\frac{2}{n})^2+.....+( a + \frac{n-1}{n})^2$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $a\in R$ .   calculate

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}( $$( a+\frac{1}{n})^2 + (a +\frac{2}{n})^2+.....+( a + \frac{n-1}{n})^2$)

As i was thinking about the formula  $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 +....+n^2= \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1) }{6}$

But here  i don't know how to solved  this tough problem as also   i don't know to approach this problem..as i was thinking a  lots  but i disn't get any clue and any hints

Thanks  In advance

Comment: If you expand $(a+\frac{k}{n})^2$ you get three terms, and if you sum those three kinds of terms over $k$ you get three summations. Presumably you know how to write down the result of all three, then add them together and divide by $n$. See what happens.

Comment: Write $1/n = \Delta x$  What does this remind you of?

Comment: Do you know about "limit of sum" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be to convert the summation to an integral:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\left(a+\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=\int_{a}^{a+1}x^2 dx$$
$$=\frac{\left( a+1 \right)^3- a^3 }{3}= a^2 +a +\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: wow amazing method but   how  a+1 come

Comment: You can see that the final term of the summation is $(a+\frac{n-1}{n})^2=(a+1)^2$ in the limit of n tending to infinity

Comment: thanks  a lots @Prathyush

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(a+\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=(n-1)a^2+\frac{2a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2$$